# How to merge or append the array of objects to another array of object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> How to merge the array of objects to another array of objects in JavaScript

Hi everyone, below I added my code.

```
   

    var person=[{"name":"Billy","age":34},{"name":"Billy","age":34}];
       var clothing=[{"shoes":"nike","shirt":"long sleeve"}, 
       {"shoes":"nike","shirt":"long sleeve"}];
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp

Comment: Seems a pretty odd requirement to have an array of objects where not all of the objects represent the same things - are you sure you're not really wanting to merge the objects themselves together so each person has their clothing? like `{"name":"Billy","age":34,"shoes":"nike","shirt":"long sleeve"}`

Comment: Agree with @Jamiec, also note that, in this case, you can remove double quotes from key names.

Answer (score 2):

you can use spread operator for this

```
const merged = [...person,...clothing]
```

Comment: I applied the [...person,...clothing] code. But, Result comes like this [0] [{"name":"Billy","age":34},{"name":"Billy","age":34}]}] and [1] [{"shoes":"nike","shirt":"long sleeve"},{"shoes":"nike","shirt":"long sleeve"}]

Comment: if you will write `[person, clothing]` then you will get this.  For your answer, you have to use the spread operator like `[...person, ...clothing]`

Answer (score 1):

```
var person=[{"name":"Billy","age":34},{"name":"Billy","age":34}];
var clothing=[{"shoes":"nike","shirt":"long sleeve"},{"shoes":"nike","shirt":"long sleeve"}];


var mergedV1 = [...person, ...clothing]
var mergedV2 = person.concat(clothing)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use spread ES6 syntax https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

```js
var person=[{"name":"Billy","age":34},{"name":"Billy","age":34}];
var clothing=[{"shoes":"nike","shirt":"long sleeve"},{"shoes":"nike","shirt":"long sleeve"}];

var merge = [...person, ...clothing]
console.log(merge)
```